It is possible to perform a simplified version of rpo with GMAT?
I have one target vehicle and a chaser. How can I perform an orbit transfer with GMAT but, at the end of the transfer this finished maintaining a relative position of 1000 m behind the target and 1000 bellow it.

Hi Goku, it would help the less informed reader to define "rpo" and "GMAT". A lot of users, including me, aren't familiar with the terminology.

Assuming you are looking to conduct an RPO maneuver on just the chaser vehicle, you could design a targeting or optimization sequence that conducts the maneuver to "catch up" to the target vehicle with your desired relative position constraints.
In order to achieve your 1 km behind/1km below, you could create a LVLH or VNB coordinate frame with the origin at your target, and use that to constrain final state of the chaser vehicle. Using the GMAT DifferentialCorrector should run fairly quickly, but if you are looking to optimize time or Delta-V, the VF13ad optimizer would be useful.

The creation of the VNB frame was the missing piece that clicked for me! I've been doing some research on how to answer this question, but your answer is elegant and sounds like the proper GMAT way

Thank you! Creating the frames in GMAT can be a bit tough, since I believe there is an LVLH frame type but no VNB. For VNB I typically use an ObjectReferenced frame with primary as spacecraft and secondary as Earth (or other body) and then define the coordinate system axes based on that orientation
